# HikariCp connection pool doesn't return the abandoned connections to pool and I am getting message too many clients connected to postgres

Tags: java, hikaricp

I have an application where user can choose any type of database(relational) provide URL, username, password and create datasource connect to database, then run SELECT queries. To connect to databases I am using HikariCp for my connection pool(before I used DBCP2 as connection timeout didn't work I changed to HikariCp). Here is my configuration

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();       
config.setDriverClassName(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(driver));      
config.setJdbcUrl(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(url));
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);       
config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
config.setMinimumIdle(3);        
config.setConnectionTestQuery(validationQuery);      
config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(jdbcTimeout)); 
config.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));
config.setMaxLifetime(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(11)); 
config.addDataSourceProperty("closeMethod", "close"); 
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

jdbcTimeout- is configurable it can be 0 -30

Running tests which using application creates queries and runs those queries, after some time I am getting an error that too many clients.

What properties should I add to return abandoned connections to the pool?

Comment: Make sure you call `close` on connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I close all connections (with autocloseable try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); ) {}). 
It is still not working.

Comment: Is there a chance that you run you tests in parallel and try to use too many connections simultaneously?

Comment: No it is not working parallel, it runs queries in order.

Comment: It should work fine then. Can some other code get connection without releasing it? It is only explanation I can think of.